# Disable Oh-My-ZSH Completion of Beginning of Filename

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I'm starting to use the directory stack in ZSH, but I've run into a problem. In an ideal directory, typing `cd -<TAB>` gives me the output of `dirs -v`. However, in some others (i.e. my Downloads folder), there's a subdirectory or file with a `-` in it, and it completes that dir. For example:

```
$ cd /
$ cd home
$ cd dxs
$ ls
Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public Templates Videos
$ cd -<TAB>
0    ~
1    /home
2    /
```

is ideal. However:

```
$ cd Downloads
$ ls
...foo bar somerepo-master baz...
$ cd -<TAB>
```

corrects to

```
$ cd somerepo-master
```

I'm used to bash-style completion and don't see a need, so is it possible to disable this behavior?

Note that I did install and configure with oh-my-zsh.

**Edit:** Using zsh -f and autoloading compinit, I have verified that it is due to Oh-My-ZSH.

Comment: Does it happen under `zsh -f` and then `autoload -U compinit; compinit` ? If not, then omz is (as usual) to blame.

Comment: Yeah, it's omz.

Comment: This is due to how *oh-my-zsh* sets up completion. [See my answer on a similar question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24359779/2992551) on how to solve this. The *OMZ* code changed a bit since I posted that answer, but the cause and solution are still the same.

Comment: @Adaephon Thanks. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I created .oh-my-zsh/custom/correct-completion.zsh, put what your answer suggests in it (minus the case insensitivity), and started a new shell. No change.

Comment: @VirtualDXS I did some checking and for me it works, even with the `'l:|=* r:|=*'` rule,  but only if there are any directories on the directory stack. Otherwise `zsh` will use complete around the `-` from the `'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*'` rule, which allows for completions like `very.c` → `verylongname.c` or in your case `-` → `somerepo-master`. If you do not usually use this kind of completion, you can just drop the `-` from the rule or even the whole rule. For reference, I use `zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' '+m:{[:lower:]}={[:upper:]}' 'l:|=* r:|=*'`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem - I forgot to create a stack before trying it. Go ahead and post it as an answer and I'll accept.